# Destination host unreachable: pinging one Ubuntu VM from another Ubuntu VM

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox

I am working on my home wireless network, trying to ping one Ubuntu (16.04) VM from another Ubuntu (16.04) VM on a Windows machine.

VM1 - *Ubuntu1604-Node2* - IP address is **192.168.56.5**

interface file looks as below:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.56.5
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.255.255
gateway 192.168.56.1
```

VM2 - *Ubuntu-Node3* - IP address is **192.168.56.102**

interface file looks as below:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.56.102
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.255.255
gateway 192.168.56.1
```

On Pinging one from another VM, I keep getting "Destination host not reachable". Any help is appreciated.


[image]


[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using VMs, you should be sure that the NAT is properly configured. Are you able to ping the VMs from their corresponding hosts?

If you are using VirtualBox (same principles for other products), you can find related info in:https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Lookt at table 6.1

```
            VM ↔ Host   VM1 ↔ VM2   VM → Internet   VM ← Internet
 Host-only     +            +          –                –
 Internal      –            +          –                –
 Bridged       +            +          +                +
 NAT           –            –          +           Port forwarding
 NAT Network   –            +          +           Port forwarding
```

I think, the easiest way is to change the default settings to NAT Network, but you can try other options.

Comment: I am using Virtualbox. yes, I can ping the VM from host. But while trying to ping back Host from VM, I again get the same message of "Destination host unreachable". I am using "Host-only networking", should I still be configuring NAT? I am not at all an expert in networking, please suggest...thanks.